# What is the product of reaction between 2‐cyclobutyl‐2‐isopropyl‐1,3‐dioxane and hydrogen with Raney nickel?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen, catalysis, heterocyclic-compounds

I have 2‐cyclobutyl‐2‐isopropyl‐1,3‐dioxane (alcohol protection) and I have to react it with $\ce{H2}$ and Raney nickel, but I don't know what the product would be.

[image: 2‐cyclobutyl‐2‐isopropyl‐1,3‐dioxane]

I have seen a similar reaction that uses sulfur atoms instead of the oxygens and at the end the entire protection is removed and leaves two $\ce{H}$ atoms in the end. I tried doing that, but my professor told me that I got it wrong. I'm thinking that there wouldn't be a reaction.

Comment: I don't think there will be any reaction

Comment: Raney nickel desulfurization applies to sulfur not oxygen deoxygenation. It is possible your professor is expecting reduction of the cyclobutane ring.

Comment: @user55119 that would have been my gut shot too